# Why am I obtaining these two errors trying to subscrive an Angular service method that retrieve data from Firestore database?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am following a course related to Angular and Firestore database and I have the following two problem:

In a controller class I have this **ngOnInit()** method:

ngOnInit() {

```
this.course = this.route.snapshot.data['course'];
this.lessons = this.coursesService.findLessons(this.course.id)
    .subscribe(
      lessons => this.lessons = lessons
    );
```

}

As you can see I am subscribing on the **coursesService.findLessons()** method, and this is the code of this service method:

findLessons(courseIs: string,
              sortOrder: OrderByDirection = 'asc',
              pageNumber = 0,
              pageSize = 3): Observable {

```
return this.db.collection('courses/${courseId}/lessons',
            ref => ref.orderBy('seqNo', sortOrder)
            .limit(pageSize)
            .startAfter(pageNumber * pageSize))
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(snaps => convertSnaps<Lesson>(snaps)),
              first()
            )
```

}

On this service method Visual Studio Code give me an error on this line:

```
sortOrder: OrderByDirection = 'asc',
```

the error says:

> Cannot find name 'OrderByDirection'.ts(2304)

On the call of this service method into my controller **ngOnInit()** method give me an error on the **this.lessons** (that is previously defined as **lessons: Lesson[];**

```
Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Lesson[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2740)
```

What exactly means? Why am I obtaining this error? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The parameters from the `ActivatedRoute` are usually serialized strings of objects. Please check if the `this.course.id` is a valid value.
2. [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) must be enclosed using backticks instead of quotation marks.

Replace

```
'courses/${courseId}/lessons'
```

with

```
`courses/${courseId}/lessons`
```